# How to hide DLL functionalities?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.0

Consider the following situation:

I have developed a DLL file `DCore`. Afterwards I developed a DLL file `DCustomer` which uses methods from `DCore`. Now I want to distribute `DCustomer` as DLL for a customer and make sure to hide all functionalities of `DCore`, so that the customer can only access the functionalities of `DCustomer`.

How can I hide the functionalities of `DCore` when creating the DLL file `DCustomer`?

Comment: Don't listen to people who say you can't do that. The good news is that you can. The bad news is that [your question is a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96732/embedding-one-dll-inside-another-as-an-embedded-resource-and-then-calling-it-fro).

Comment: @Renan thank you for pointing me to the other question. Isn't there also a possible solution with friend assemblies or signed assemblies?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood I don't see any mention of either in the marked answer. Anyway, I haven't tried anything myself - I just knew this has been asked again and again in SO, so I pointed that out. You may want to try the tools suggested in that question, maybe you'll find something that'll do the trick for you. Good luck and happy coding :)

Comment: You need to define what "hide" means. As @Jon pointed out as soon as assembly is in user's hand in any shape (including obfuscated/hidden as resource/protected with `InternalsVisibleTo`) user can call methods/look at code...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov "Hide" in the sense that the customer can only access the methods in `DCustomer` and none of the methods in `DCore` (even if they are public).

Comment: Not enough info - you need to think why simple text warning "usage of XXXX assembly directly is not supported" is not enough. Warning would stop normal users, but you need to know how far you want to go with discouraging to look into/use of internal assembly.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov counterquestion: How far can I go? I would like to discourage as much as possible with a reasonable amount of effort.

Comment: Making everything in DCore internal and using `InternalsVisibleTo` is probably only cheap discouraging solution... @Renan suggestion to make DCore resource file and extract before execution will be pain to sort out runtime dependencies (but slightly more discouraging for users)... Obfuscation and more complicated approaches should be relatively easy to find by searching for "obfuscation"...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing much you can do about it.

But do check out [StrongNameIdentityPermissionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.strongnameidentitypermissionattribute.aspx)

I would also request you to check out this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805461/how-to-protect-dlls)