# Encrypt Asp.net webmatrix source code

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, asp.net-webpages

I have an application developed using Asp.Net Webmatrix and want to publish source code into client server but protect my source code from being hampered or used.......Is there a way to convert my source code to dll files or somehow hide it. Is there a way around this?

Comment: How are you publishing to the server? In visual studio when you publish, all .cs files are compiled into a dll and used on the server. ( The .cs files don't go with it as long as these files are set to compile)

Comment: If you don't trust your server, you shouldn't use it at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805461/how-to-protect-dlls

Comment: You can't compile your cshtml or vbhtml files. You would need to convert to web forms or MVC if you need to protect your source code. @Slaks, it may not be about trusting your own server, it could be that you you need to provide a website to a client but don't want to provide source code.

Comment: @John: The client can still decompile it.