# Restrict to load netframework DLL in Visual Studio or other developer project

Tags: visual-studio, dll, .net-framework-version

I have a Netframework DLL project in Visual Studio and the DLL is compiled in Release mode and used in another project, how I can restrict to load or the use about the DLL by another person than could stolen my DLL and use in his/her project?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with internal class and method:

**Some class in My dll:**

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("FriendAssembly")]
namespace MiLibrary
{

    internal class Class1
    {
        internal static string GetName()
        {
            return "My Name";
        }
    }
}
```

**Another Project in some class:**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            txbText.Text = MiLibrary.Class1.GetName();
        }
    }
}
```

Only **"FriendAssembly"** has access to **Class1**. **"Another Project"** must have the assembly name as **"FriendAssembly"** (Menu Project -> Properties of "Another Project" -> Application -> Assembly Name)

[InternalsVisibleToAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Related questions in Stackoverflow:

[Protect C# DLL from third party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109761/protect-c-sharp-dll-from-third-party)

[How to protect dlls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805461/how-to-protect-dlls)